# WindowsAPICodePack - Is System.KindText value consistent regardless of Globalized Culture?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

I'm using WindowsAPICodePack to determine a file's type (image, audio or video).

I'm using the return value from

```
string mediaType = GetValueString(fileObj.Properties.GetProperty(SystemProperties.System.KindText));
```

It returns "Picture", "Music", and "Video" for the three types.

My question is will this value be consistent regardless of  Globalized Culture?
If not, is there another way to get these media Types from a file name.

Comment: So far as I can tell, rather than using `System.KindText`, you should use [`System.Kind`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787521.aspx). That way you can simply bypass your original question and not even need to know the answer to that.

Comment: @David Heffernan, if I am reading the System.Kind property correctly, it appears to be an array of strings.  The array simply holds the value of System.KindText. But I'm a newbie to WindowsAPICodePack, so...

Comment: Looks like an enum to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, SystemProperties.System.PerceivedType is the right property to use. I returns an interger representing the type of file.

Related link
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx